# UICollectionView Crash layoutAttributesForElementsInRect

Tags: uicollectionview

I have a tableview and collectionview in view controller. The collection view gets populated based on selections made in the table view. I want the collectionview to be updated without animation. The collection view gets updated when a selection is made on the table. I'm also using a custom collectionview layout (UICollectionViewLayout). Here's the code that updates the collection view:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {  
  guard var data = measurementData?[indexPath.item] else { return }  
  if data.name != unitData.selectedMeasurement {   
     unitData.selectedMeasurement = data.name   
     unitConversionTable?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()  
     //self.unitConversionTable?.reloadData()  
     UIView.performWithoutAnimation({ self.unitConversionTable?.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0)) })   
   }  
}
```

The problem is that the application crashes if the entire collection view does not fit on the screen; unless I use reloadData() (which comes with the unwanted animations). Here's the actual message.

> 2016-04-13 22:42:23.367 aio Calculator[6288:273528] * Assertion
>   failure in -[UICollectionViewData
>   layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UICollectionViewData.m:666
>   2016-04-13 22:42:23.978 xxx [6288:273528] *Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no
>   UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for
>   -layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: {length = 2, path = 0 - 10}'

This particular case has 12 cells in the CV. But only 10 are displayed based on the result of layoutAttributesForElementsInRect (because only 10 fit).

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {   
     var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()   
     cache.forEach({attributes in   
       if CGRectIntersectsRect(attributes.frame, rect) {   
         layoutAttributes.append(attributes)   
       }  
     })  
print("layoutAttributesForElementsInRect \(rect) has \(layoutAttributes.count) attributes")   
   return layoutAttributes }
```

My print statements show that there are 12 items.

> prepareLayout NumOfitems:12

But only 10 attributes.

> layoutAttributesForElementsInRect (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 736.0) has 10
>   attributes

So, everything appears to be correct; at least as far as I understand how it's suppose to work.

Why is the app crashing?

What am I missing?

Thanks!

==================
Update:

OK. I think I know what's going on. I re-read all the documentation. The definition for layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) clearly states:

**Returns the layout attributes for all of the cells and views in the specified rectangle.**

But then I started looking at the a sample projects and found
[Collection View Transition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CollectionViewTransition/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013415) which clearly returns all the cached attributes instead of just the ones that intersect with the given rect. I changed layoutAttributesForElementsInRect to return all cached attributes and now everything works fine.

Comment: See Update and looks like returning all cached attributes in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect() works better; at least in my case.

Comment: After further reading I found that the Apple doc states that you must implement layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath() which also eliminates the crash.